# Spring boot @Transactional not calling my catch block

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, custom-error-handling

Why is the ConstraintViolationException catch block not executing below when I use @Transactional. It does when I remove @Transactional. I want it to execute so I can do some custom error handling. I do understand that Spring wraps my code in a proxy which does the transaction management and that checked exceptions are not rolledback by default. But I still can't connect the dots here:

```java
@Transactional
public PropertyInserterResult insertOrUpdateProperty(ScalerProperty property, 
        MultipartFile logo, ScalerUser loggedInUser) {
    ScalerLogo scalerLogo = null;
    int success = 0, error = 0;
    try {
          logger.info("Logo size:"+logo.getSize());
          if(logo.getSize() > 0) {
              scalerLogo = new ScalerLogo(logo.getBytes());
              scalerLogoRepository.save(scalerLogo);
          }
          
          scalerPropertyRepository.save(property.prepareToSave(loggedInUser, scalerLogo));
          logger.info("Prop {}:{} inserted for {}",property.getKey(), property.getValue(), property.getCreatedBy().getUsername());
          ++success;
      } catch (org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException cve) { 
          logger.error("Dupe key");
          handleDuplicate(property);
          ++error;
      } 
    
    return new PropertyInserterResult(success, error);
}
```

Comment: Spring translates exceptions to one in the `DataAccessException` hierarchy so it (normally) won't throw hibernate exceptions. Check `HibernateExceptionTranslator`

Comment: Ohh same issue. I don't get to catch the exceptions for custom error handling, either. I think there should be some workaround as this is a common usecase.